# read content within parentheses and compare numbers in perl

Tags: perl

I have the content of file as :

```
(0872) "ss_current" (1 of 1)
(0873) "ss_current_6oct" (0 of 1)
```

I want to read each line of file and then get the content between last parentheses i.e.

```
(1 of 1)
(0 of 1)
```

and compare the numbers if they are equal i.e. number before and after "of" are equal.
My code:

```
my @cs;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ($_ =~ /\((.*?)\)/) {
        my $temp = $1;
        print $temp, "\n";
    }
}
```

But this giving the content as `0872` or `0873`

Answer (score 5):

Your regex is only picking up the first set of brackets. Make it more specific, and you can pick the `(1 of 1)` or `(0 of 1)`:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    # \d+ means match one or more adjacent numbers
    # brackets capture the match in $1 and $2
    if ($_ =~ /\((\d+) of (\d+)\)/) {
        if ($1 == $2) {
           # they are equal! print out the line (or do whatever)
           # (the line is set to the special variable $_ while processing the file)
           print "$_";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my ($first, $second) = /\((\d+) of (\d+)\)/;
    print "$first of $second\n" if $first == $second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not specific enough as there are more than one set of parenthesis in each line.

It's possible to use a regex to match the exact condition you're wanting using [backreferences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print if /\((\d+) of \1\)/;
}

__DATA__
(0872) "ss_current" (1 of 1)
(0873) "ss_current_6oct" (0 of 1)
```

Outputs:

```
(0872) "ss_current" (1 of 1)
```

Note that this is kind of an advanced technique, as one must be sure to enforce boundary conditions to avoid matching a substring in an undesired way.  For this reason, I'd actually recommend using a technique like alarmed alien uses if you're a beginner.